# Creating Binary World Representation - How to Set a Bit in a Long and then Print the Long

Tags: java

I am using java to model `Conway's Game of Life`. I am setting a bit in a long and then printing the bit.

My current `setCell` method is changing the specified bit and all of the bits after that bit index, rather than just the bit at the specified index.

How do I need to change my class?

```
public class TinyLife {

private final int side_length = 8;
private long world;

public TinyLife(long world){
    this.world = world;
}

public void printWorld(){
    System.out.println("\nThe current world:");
    for (int row = 0; row < side_length; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < side_length; col++){
            System.out.print(getCell(col, row) ? " # " : " _ ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public boolean getCell(int col, int row){
    int index = (row * side_length) + col;
    long a = world >> index; // Shift the bits by position.
    long c = a & 1;
    return (c == 1);
}

public void setCell(int col, int row, boolean value) {
    int index = col + (row * side_length);
    System.out.println(index);
    /* I think that the error is below. Why are all the bits to the left of the bit at the index also being set? */
    if (value) {
        world |= (1 << index);
    }
    else world = world & ~(1 << index);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long first_world = 0x20272000027202L;
    TinyLife world = new TinyLife(first_world);
    world.printWorld();
    System.out.println("Binary rep before setCell = " + Long.toBinaryString(world.world));
    world.setCell(7, 3, true);
    System.out.println("Binary rep after setCell = " + Long.toBinaryString(world.world));
    world.printWorld();
}
}
```

> Expected printout:

```
The current world:

 _  #  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  #  _  _  #  #  #  _ 
 _  #  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  #  _  _ 
 #  #  #  _  _  #  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  #  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _ 

Binary rep before setCell = 100000001001110010000000000000000000100111001000000010
31
Binary rep after setCell = 100000001001110010000010000000000000100111001000000010

The current world:

 _  #  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  #  _  _  #  #  #  _ 
 _  #  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _  # 
 _  _  _  _  _  #  _  _ 
 #  #  #  _  _  #  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  #  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _
```

---

> Actual printout:

```
The current world:

 _  #  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  #  _  _  #  #  #  _ 
 _  #  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  #  _  _ 
 #  #  #  _  _  #  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  #  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _ 

Binary rep before setCell = 100000001001110010000000000000000000100111001000000010
31
Binary rep after setCell = 1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000100111001000000010

The current world:

 _  #  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  #  _  _  #  #  #  _ 
 _  #  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _  # 
 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
```

(Note that I added a few line breaks to the text above to try to make my question easier to read)

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `1 << index` is an `int` operation, not a `long` operation.

With inputs `col = 7, row = 3`, the calculation `index = col + (row * side_length)` yields the value `31`, which in an `int` value is the **sign bit**.

`world |= (1 << index)` then widens the `int` value to a `long` using *sign-extension*, setting all upper 32 bits to 1's.

Change code to `world |= (1L << index)`, so the bit-shift is done as a `long`. That way it'll also work for `index` value above 31.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that 1 << index is an int operation, not a long
>   operation.

That's correct from **Andreas**. I would like to add to this, that you use index calculation in 3 places, but this problem appears in only one of them. I think you could extract it to the separate method and use it. It could be more clear.

```
// convert given `cal` and `row` to long with single bit set
private long bit(int col, int row) {
    // optionally you could add check for correct col and row (0 <= col (row) <= side_length - 1)
    return 1L << (row * side_length) + col;
}
```

then you can simplify your code:

```
public boolean getCell(int col, int row) {
    return (world & bit(col, row)) != 0;
}

public void setCell(int col, int row, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        world |= bit(col, row);
    else
        world &= ~bit(col, row);
}
```

Comment: Why did you put parenthesis around the multiplication? Everybody is familiar with the [precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) rule that `*` is applied before `+`, so we don't need parenthesis to "document" that, but do most people know off-hand what precedence between `<<` and `+` is? In fact, `+` *is* applied before `<<`, so expression could be just `1L << row * side_length + col`, but since many people probably aren't familiar with precedence of `<<`, you should change expression to `1L << (row * side_length + col)`

Comment: Good suggestion of helper method. +1